# Edit buttons and more with PushWoosh

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushwoosh

I am currently changing from Urban airship to Pushwoosh for my iOS and Android application! Everything seems to be working just fine, but am having some minor issues.

1. Is it possible to change what the buttons says within the app? When I get an push within the app is says "Cancel" and "OK!".
2. Is it possible to set a push only to show outside the app and not when you are within the app?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

EDIT:

Here is how I send pushes from my server using PHP:

```
include("includes/pushwoosh.php");
pwCall( 'createMessage', array(
'application' => PW_APPLICATION,
'auth' => PW_AUTH,
'notifications' => array(
            array(
                'send_date' => 'now',
                'devices' => array($row['devicetoken']),
                'content' => $userName.' '.$languagestring[59], 
                'data' => array( 'custom' => 'json data' )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Can I set some kind of parameter within this to make my issues work?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it from your server.

> action-loc-key
>
> string or null
>
> If a string is specified, displays an alert with two buttons, whose
>   behavior is described in Table 3-1. However, iOS uses the string as a
>   key to get a localized string in the current localization to use for
>   the right button’s title instead of “View”. If the value is null, the
>   system displays an alert with a single OK button that simply dismisses
>   the alert when tapped. See “Localized Formatted Strings” for more
>   information.

Comment: I not really sure what you mean. I have edited my initial question with the code I use to send push. maybe that helps?

Comment: @Mansa I'm referring to the push notification JSON payload specified by [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW15). The `JSON` you are sending seems different. I don't know what's the format that `PushWoosh` accepts.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK displays the alert by default, and you can switch it off in the PushNotificationManager.m class (https://github.com/shaders/push-notifications-sdk/blob/master/SDK/iPhone/Classes/PushNotificationManager.m). You should edit line #158

showPushnotificationAlert = TRUE; // put FALSE if you don't want to display the notification.

Regarding changing button texts, you can edit them in the same code, lines #497-494:

```
if(!isPushOnStart && showPushnotificationAlert && msgIsString) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:self.appName message:alertMsg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    alert.tag = ++internalIndex;
    [pushNotifications setObject:userInfo forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:internalIndex]];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard method to change action button caption in Pushwoosh API yet. But i found a workaround.

You can inject any data you want into final payload via "ios_root_params" argument.

Action button caption can be changed if key aps.alert.action-loc-key exists in payload. You can send following request to do that:

```
{"request":{
"auth":"AUTH TOKEN",
"application":"APP CODE",
"notifications":[{
     "send_date":"now",
     "ios_root_params":{
        "aps":{
           "alert":{
              "body":"message body",
              "action-loc-key":"custom caption"
           }
        }
     }
   }]
}}
```

Any json you define in "ios_root_params" will be merged with push payload and ios_root_params has priority when merging.

You can omit field "content" because "aps" dictionary will be overwritten with our data.